# Is it ok to use guillemets for quotations?

Tags: punctuation, writing, orthography

Is it okay to use guillemets <sup>(1)</sup> for quotations in English?  They are used in French.

<sup>(1)</sup> [Guillemets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) are angle quotation marks, «, », ‹, and ›

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, standard English only ever uses the double-quotes (or, if quoting something inside the double-quotes, single-quotes) for its delimitation of quotations.

(As noted in the comments, if you need to go more than two layers deep, just keep alternating single and double.)

Comment: But what do you do when you quote a text which already has a quote inside a quote (or uses quotation-marks to show irony in the first quote), i.e. when you *need* a third level of quotation-marks?

Comment: @Stephen – from [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/single-quotes-versus-double-quotes.aspx): _Imagine you've interviewed Aardvark for a magazine article about his harrowing ordeal with an arrow, and he said, “Squiggly saved my life when he yelled, 'Watch out, Aardvark.'” If you're ever in the extremely rare position of having to nest another quotation inside a sentence like that, you would use double quotation marks again for the third nested quote._

Comment: Double outside, single within is the practice in standard *American* English.  I've been informed by my British friends that in standard British English, it's single outside and double within.  (But no guillemets, unless you are quoting French from a French source, and probably even then only in a scholarly publication.)

Comment: Is English really as rigid as it seems here? For example, I don't expect to be "scolded" in Italian if I use double-quotes or an em-dash instead of «» for direct speech or citations. Isn't a matter of personal style and taste? I would accept it as a rule enforced by specific media that want to have a consistent style (consistent wrt the media itself). But I do not accept it as a strict ortographic rule of a language.

Comment: @ShinTakezou,  Standard English keyboards and character sets (ASCII, EBCDIC) don't even include the guillemet characters; they're just not part of our standard orthography.  Frankly I'm surprised wikipedia even lists them at all on the [Punctuation of English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation_of_English#Guillemets) page.

Comment: @Hellion As said in the prev comment: I do not accept it as a strict ortho rule of **any** language. «» “” are not part of std It. keyboard neither, and in Italian texts use «» or “” for direct speech (often "—", too), citation, "special" quoting. Never heard thing like "Italian uses «», not “”" or the opposite. It's style, not orthography; or, if you prefer, It.ortho rules accept a wider range of choices (maybe not German usage like »«, but if I use them I don't expect a mark for an *ortographic* error: odd unusual choice, that's it), so I'm inclined to think others should, too.

Comment: @ShinTakezou Well, it's definitely *weird* to use them in English, but if you really want to, the world won't end :-)  If a teacher wants to mark it wrong, or if an editor wants to change it, well, that's up to them.  But if you're not in a position where you have to worry about that sort of thing, do as you like, I suppose!  T h e r e a r e n o a b s o l u t e r u l e s t h a t e v e r y o n e m u s t o b e y j u s t c o n v e n t i o n s t h a t p e o p l e u s u a l l y d o a s a f a v o r t o t h e r e a d e r I f y o u w a n t t o f l o u t t h o s e  c o n v e n t i o n s g o f o r i t !

Comment: If a quotation includes apostrophes (') or back-ticks (`), I try to use single-quotes (' ') and double-quotes(" ") in ways that minimize the confusion between the apostrophes and the single-quotes.  Sometimes this means I put the outermost quote in single-quotes, and alternate from there.

Comment: @snailboat with the last sentence I hope you're not trying to do a *silly* analogy to force comparing word spacing convention(s) with the harmless choice between "…" “…” «…» »…« 〈…〉 and so on. It'd be **really weird** if you get confused by the use «» instead of “” as you get confused by omitting spaces between words or equally spacing each letters. For the rest, I mainly agree: if my publisher say I must use “”, I will. On blogs, posts and comments on SO and other places, people pointing **and fixing** details like those, are *weird* to me, to say the least.

Comment: @ShinTakezou They're similar in that they both present a puzzle that English readers have to figure out, distracting them from what they're reading.  Many English readers will have never seen «…» before and will only be able to figure out that they're quotation marks from context.  Make no mistake—you're ignoring English orthography when you use guillemets.  Do it if you like, but be aware that it's strange.

Comment: @snailboat They're not similar at all: magnitude matters. If English readers are puzzled/distracted by reading «» instead of “” the same way a reader of any language using latin script and spacing word is puzzled by reading 〈a s e n t e n c e l i k e t h i s〉, then they have a serious problem. We figure out a lot of things only thanks to the context. Grammars and orthographies are not immutable; guess what makes them change.

Comment: `([{}])` is max for me.